# Extracting covariance of level-2 residuals from lme4 output

Tags: r, lme4

I need to know how to extract the level-2 residual covariance from a random-slopes lmer object.

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
summary(fm1)
```

This is the random effects table

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 612.09   24.740       
          Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
 Residual             654.94   25.592       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
```

I know that the value `0.07` under the `Corr` is the covariance correlation coefficient and I can use this to calculate the actual level-2 covariance. However I am not 100% sure that what I am extracting is right. I tried

```
as.data.frame(VarCorr(model))
```

and got

```
       grp        var1 var2       vcov       sdcor
1  Subject (Intercept) <NA> 612.089751 24.74044768
2  Subject        Days <NA>  35.071662  5.92213326
3  Subject (Intercept) Days   9.604335  0.06555134
4 Residual        <NA> <NA> 654.941040 25.59181589
```

Is the value in the 3rd row in the `sdcor` column what I'm looking for, the covariance correlation coefficient? It seems obvious (0.065 rounded up to 0.07) but I want to make certain.

And what is the value in the 3rd row under `vcov`? That doesn't appear in the summary output anywhere.

Comment: After doing some reading I worked out that the value in the 3rd row of the vcov column *is* in fact the covariance of the level-2 residuals. Will leave this up in case someone else needs it.