# lme4 level-2 residual covariance and standard error

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to reproduce the examples in Multilevel Analysis by Snijders & Bosker but I can't find how to calculate S.E. of the covariance of the level-2 residual.

[image: Page 86]

I found 2 related questions on SO:

[Extracting covariance of level-2 residuals from lme4 output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476408/extracting-covariance-of-level-2-residuals-from-lme4-output)

[Standard Error of variance component from the output of lmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694812/standard-error-of-variance-component-from-the-output-of-lmer)

I used the data and script provided by Snijders:

https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/mlbook2_r_dat.zip

https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~snijders/ch45.r

```
# Read data
mlbook_red <- read.table("mlbook2_r.dat", header=TRUE)
library(lme4)
# Example 5.4
mlb54 <- lmer(langPOST ~ IQ_verb*ses + sch_iqv*sch_ses
                        + (IQ_verb|schoolnr), data = mlbook_red,
                        REML = FALSE)

dd.ML <- lme4:::devfun2(mlb54,useSc=TRUE,signames=FALSE)
vv <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(mlb54)) ## need ML estimates!
pars <- vv[,"sdcor"]
library("numDeriv")
hh1 <- hessian(dd.ML,pars)
vv2 <- 2*solve(hh1)  ## 2* converts from log-likelihood to deviance scale
sqrt(diag(vv2))  ## get standard errors
```

The numbers I got are:

```
[1] 0.1898 0.1539 0.1014 0.0744
```

I don't think these numbers are anywhere near `1.050 0.069 0.204 0.907`. The coefficients are right in `as.data.frame(VarCorr(mlb54))$vcov`: `[1] 8.369 0.164 -0.929 37.378`.

Can anyone help explain what went wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is a good question but I haven't had time for it yet ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you! In the previous question, your answer mentioned the order after `pars <- vv[, "sdcor"] ## will need to be careful about order if using this for ## a random-slopes model ...` Can you elaborate more about the order? In this mlb54 example, pars order is the same as the order of the random part in the table. But I can't get the S.E. right. I also tried the data with Stata and the result seems in the ballpark, although the numbers aren't exactly the same... Thanks again!